# Load xml data from an url like this : /index.php/site/projects/ as a php variable

Tags: php, xml

I need to read xml data generated by a php file(of Expression Engine) on passing url like `/index.php/site/projects/` into a php object. (*note that it is not a physical file*). How can I do that ?

*Since I am not quite aware of php stuff please pardon me in case I have asked something silly & let me know in case I can add more information.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simplexml_load_file(string $filename) to this end. Just pass into this function the full URL such as:

$myXMLContent = simplexml_load_file('http://myserver.com/index.php/site/projects/');

Then if you need to use this information, note that all nodes that are not repetitive will be accessible directly using:

```
$myXMLContent->nodename
```

Then all attributes are part of an array of the node, so:

```
<nodename id="6" name="blabla"><subnode>Content</subnode></nodename>
```

Can be fetched as:

```
echo $myXMLContent['id'];
echo $myXMLContent['name'];
echo $myXMLContent->subnode;
```

And if you have many subnodes at once, you can use:

```
echo $myXMLContent->subnode[2]
```

To get the 3rd subnode.

This is the best i can do to help you, the rest can be found at: http://www.php.net/manual/fr/book.simplexml.php

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php), the [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php) class, or [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

**Edit:**

An example taken from the documentation of simplexml_load_file

```
<?php
// The file test.xml contains an XML document with a root element
// and at least an element /[root]/title.

if (file_exists('http://domain.com/index.php/site/projects/')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://domain.com/index.php/site/projects/');

    print_r($xml);
} else {
    exit('Failed to open the xml file.');
}
?>
```

I'm not an expert on this, but there are lots of good hints, examples, and notes on the page I linked to.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please point me to right direction by writing a line of code as to how to include a url inside these xml loading functions ?